# Getting the Age using Parameter Value and Current Date [CRYSTAL REPORT]

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to get the age of my user in crystal report using parameter and current date.

This is my formula for the crystal report.

```
INT ((CurrentDate - {?txtbdate}) / 365.25)
```

> For example: the date in **{?txtbdate}** is **1996-07-29** and today
>   is **2018-10-25**.
>
> The age must be **22**.

When I execute it, a popup message appear saying "A number is required here."

Answer (score 0):

This is just a blind guest, but you must first convert the data before doing the math,

For ex. `(INT (CurrentDate) - INT ({?txtbdate})) / 365.25`

each value must be Identified as integer before subtracting

**The Right way of doing it:**

you can use the DateDiff function on the 
ex. `DateDiff("yyyy", CurrentDate, {?txtbdate})`